# overriding config.js variables for express/node app based on environment

Tags: node.js, configuration, express

I have a config.js that has all my variables setup.

I want to create a config.global.js and have config.production.js override a few of them and config.development.js override a few of them.

Here's an example config.development.js:

```
var config = {};    

config.env = 'development';
config.hostname = 'example.dev';
config.appname = 'Example.com';
config.site_url = 'http://example.dev:8080';

module.exports = config;
```

I am thinking I can just do this in config.development.js (and config.production.js) to override:

```
var config = require('config.global.js');

config.env = 'development';
config.hostname = 'example.dev';
config.appname = 'Example.com';
config.site_url = 'http://example.dev:8080';

module.exports = config;
```

And then in app.js, I could do this:

```
var cfg = require('config.' + ( process.ENV.APP_ENV || 'development' ) + '.js');
app.set('domain', cfg.hostname);
```

What are some other ways to define application config variables?

Comment: Usually the environment variable is `NODE_ENV`. Other than that, this seems fine. Also, I'd `lowercase()` said variable, so that you don't have troubles if the variable is all uppercase and you're in a case-(in)sentive OS (Mac OS vs linux).

Comment: which variable would you lowercase? the NODE_ENV?

Comment: `process.ENV.NODE_ENV.lowercase()`. By the way if I recall correctly Express has some helpers for environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use one JSON file with settings for all the environment. Your approach may not scale well when you introduce more environments. You can get the correct set of properties by looking up NODE_ENV property and using it to pick set of properties from your environment.

I blogged about it sometime ago in [Bootstraping a Node.js App for Dev/Prod Environment](http://himanshu.gilani.info/blog/2012/09/26/bootstraping-a-node-dot-js-app-for-dev-slash-prod-environment/). Specifically read "**Simulating production environment during testing**" for an example of how to do it.

Comment: I think my approach scales very well actually. I only override whatever is in config.global.js. Why do you say it doesn't scale?

Comment: In your approach you have already mentioned three files `config.global.js`, `config.development.js` and `config.production.js`. 

With this approach When you add new environments like `staging`, `qa`, etc then you will have to create new js files. If you store all the properties in a JSON file then everything will be consolidated in one location rather than in multiple files. If you want some default properties then you can add a default section in JSON file. Now write a helper function to return env. specific values. IF no env. specific value exists but default value exists return that.

Comment: I see your point. If you have more environments, it can grow the number of files. Not sure how I would specific a global and override in one file though.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow himanshu's advice and use a single config file, you can use prototypal inheritance to avoid duplication:

```
var config = {};    

config.base = {};
config.base.env = 'development';
config.base.hostname = 'example.dev';
config.base.appname = 'Example.com';
config.base.site_url = 'http://example.dev:8080';

config.development = Object.create(config.base);
config.development.debugLevel = 'high';
...

config.production = Object.create(config.base);
config.production.debugLevel = 'low';
...

module.exports = config;
```

`Object.create()` is an ES5 function that creates a new empty object with a specified prototype.

Comment: how do i use it though for an environment? I would expect to be able to do require('./config').hostname and get either the dev or prod hostname.

Comment: Something like `var cfg = require('./config')[process.ENV.APP_ENV || 'development'];`

Comment: that's kind of annoying to have to do that everywhere I need cfg.whatever. Thanks though, I will think about this. Maybe autoloading in a wrapper.

Comment: Consider putting the env selection in your config: `module.exports = config[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];`